# php while loop inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

Here this line `$find_cond = str_replace('|',' ',$rem_exp);` returns 225 and 245 number.

I want to get the records based on these two id number. But this below code returns the output repeatedly.

How do I properly put the while loop code inside a foreach?

```
foreach($arr_val as $key => $val)
{
    $c_subsubtopic = str_replace('-','_',$subsubtopic);
    $rem_exp = $val[$c_subsubtopic];
    $find_cond = str_replace('|',' ',$rem_exp);
    $sql = "SELECT a.item_id, a.item_name, a.item_url, b.value_url, b.value_name, b.value_id FROM ".TBL_CARSPEC_ITEMS." a, ".TBL_CARSPEC_VALUES." b WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.item_url = '".$subsubtopic."' AND value_id = '".$find_cond."' AND a.status = '1'";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql)))
    {
        echo $r['value_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to print $sql and run sql to check the result first.

Comment: Like he said.  Pull your data set first.  Then run your while statement against that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are redoing the sql query at every iteration of the loop, thus resetting the results internal pointer, so you keep fetching the same array.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql)
```

should be on it's own line before the while loop, and then

```
while($r = msql_fetch_array($res))
```

This will properly increment through the $res list.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and you are done

As you were getting may get multiple id in the string after replacing it so its better to use IN the where clause

```
foreach($arr_val as $key => $val)
{
    $c_subsubtopic = str_replace('-','_',$subsubtopic);
    $rem_exp = $val[$c_subsubtopic];
    $find_cond = str_replace('|',',',$rem_exp);
    $sql = "SELECT a.item_id, a.item_name, a.item_url, b.value_url, b.value_name, b.value_id FROM ".TBL_CARSPEC_ITEMS." a, ".TBL_CARSPEC_VALUES." b WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.item_url = '".$subsubtopic."' AND value_id IN('".$find_cond."') AND a.status = '1'";
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql)))
    {
        echo $r['value_name'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Beginner can you please post what you are getting in $subsubtopic?

Comment: on which basis you are using IN instead of = ?

Comment: @RamSharma It was just an assumption as the output was repeated and then i asked him for the value in the variable

Comment: @Veerendra, pls. don't assume. Let the user explain his issue.

Comment: @Veerendra : In my $subsubtopic I got engine-description. engine_description is my column name. so, i'm using str_replace